# Ajax autocomplete for Jquery, how to send dynamic parameters id

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am using the jquery autocomplete plugin, and I have several dynamic input, which I can not do is fill each input with the corresponding id.
Here I show my code
In my js

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="0"  align="middle">
    <td width="100%">
        <input type="text" name="resourcesIds[0]" size="107" value="${requestScope.form.resourceId}">
<span><img src="gif/b.gif" width="7" height="1"><input type="text" name="description[0]" size="107" class="description" value="${requestScope.form.description}" ></span>
<span><a href="#" id="somebutton"><img src="gif/new.gif" border="0"  /></a></span>
    </td>
</table>
<table id="containerResources">

</table>
```

In my js :

```
 var auto = {
            serviceUrl: 'provide.do',
            paramName: 'cmd',
            dataType : "json",
            transformResult: function(response) {
                return {
                    suggestions: $.map(response, function(dataItem) {
                        return { value: dataItem.provideId+ " - " +  dataItem.provideName, data: dataItem.provideId};

                    })
                };
            }
        };

    var a = $('.description').autocomplete(auto);
    a.autocomplete().setOptions({onSelect: function(suggestion){
         $("input[name=resourcesIds[0]").val(suggestion.data);
    }});

    var wrapper = $("#containerResources");
    $("#somebutton").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var numItems = $('.itemResource').length;
        var numItemsFixed = numItems + 1;
        var rowFile='<tr id="recurso_'+numItemsFixed+'" class="itemResource"><td width="100%;"><input type="text" name="resourcesIds['+numItemsFixed+']" size="107" value=""><input type="text" name="descriptions['+numItemsFixed+']" size="107" class="descriptions"/></td><td width="100px" align="center"><a href="#" class="remove_field">eliminar</a></td></tr>';
        $(wrapper).append(rowFile);
        var a = $('.description',wrapper).autocomplete(auto);
        a.autocomplete().setOptions({onSelect: function(suggestion){
            alert( $("input[name=resourcesIds["+ numItemsFixed +"]]").val(suggestion.data));    

        }});
```

This code does not fill any input with the id

Comment: I attach the plugin documentation, thanks for the help https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[name=resourcesIds[0]").val(suggestion.data);
```

You are missing a closing square bracket, It should be :

```
$("input[name=resourcesIds[0]]").val(suggestion.data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it still does not work, it does not show me anything in the input, thanks for the help